# Find and delete folder but not content

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm trying to find all folders named `b` and delete them, without deleting their content (whether folders, files, hidden files, ...).

So for example, a file in a path `/a/b/c/file` should become `/a/c/file`

Here's what I've tried, which doesn't work :

```
find -type d -name b -exec mv {}/* {} \; -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find -type d -name b -exec echo "mv {}/* {}/..; rmdir {}" \; | sh
```

Comment: `mv` and `rmdir` handle both correct.

Comment: I like this solution even if you can find some problems in the case it just exists a directory with the same name of the one you want to move up in the father directory (when you perform `mv {}/* {}/`. e.g.). With files instead you will overwrite the ones in the upper directory without prompt. To manage all I think it's cosy to do a script

Comment: Cyrus, it's not the mv and rmdir that I'm worried about regarding the hidden files, but the wildcard.

Comment: Add `shopt -s dotglob; ` before `mv` and replace `sh` by `bash` to catch dot files  and dirs too.

Comment: ok thanks. (as a side note, how did you answer that quick to my comment ? Do you get notified when I insert a comment, and if so, how ?)

Comment: @Cyrus Why the pipe instead of `sh -c`?